# What happens "behind the scenes" if I call `None == x` in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, equality, nonetype, comparison-operators

I am learning and playing around with Python and I came up with the following test code (please be aware that *I would not write productive code like that*, but when learning new languages I like to play around with the language's corner cases):

```
a = None    
print(None == a) # I expected True, I got True

b = 1
print(None == b) # I expected False, I got False

class MyNone:
    # Called if I compare some myMyNone == somethingElse
    def __eq__(self, __o: object) -> bool:
        return True

c = MyNone()
print (None == c) # !!! I expected False, I got True !!!
```

**Please see the very last line of the code example.**

How can it be that `None == something`, where something is clearly not `None`, return `True`? I would have expected that result for `something == None`, but not for `None == something`.

I expected that it would call `None is something` behind the scenes.

So I think the question boils down to: **How does the `__eq__` method of the `None` singleton object look like and how could I have found that out?**

---

PS: I am aware of [PEP-0008](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/) and its quote

> Comparisons to singletons like None should always be done with is or is not, never the equality operators.

but I *still* would like to know why `print (None == c)` in the above example returns `True`.

Comment: pretty sure the left arguments `eq` implementation is used, try `c == None`

Comment: @FilipHaglund The whole point of my question is that I  _did not_ write `c == None` (which would directly call "my `__eq__` method") but `None == c`.

Comment: *"How does the `__eq__` method of the None singleton object"* - Why don't you just try it?

Comment: @KellyBundy That's what I did, I tried it, I could not make sense of it, and that's why this question exists.

Comment: What was the result?

Comment: The result is in the question, it returns `True`... I don't know where you are going with your comments? Also, I asked _How does the `__eq__` method of the None singleton object **look like**_, so you left out the most important part of my question when you "repeated" it.

Comment: No it's not in the question. Again: what did you get when you tried that method, i.e., when you did `print(None.__eq__(c))`?

Comment: Thank you for the input. I did not know that when using `==` more than `None.__eq__(c)` (which returns `NotImplemented`) happens. The answer by VPfB points out that some special behavior takes place when `__eq__` returns `NotImplemented`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In fact, `None`'s type does not have its own `__eq__` method; within Python we can see that it apparently inherits from the base class `object`:

```py
>>> type(None).__eq__
<slot wrapper '__eq__' of 'object' objects>
```

But this is not really what's going on in the source code. The implementation of `None` can be found in [`Objects/object.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/74d5f61ebd1cb14907bf7dae1ad9c1e676707bc5/Objects/object.c#L1681) in the CPython source, where we see:

```c
PyTypeObject _PyNone_Type = {
    PyVarObject_HEAD_INIT(&PyType_Type, 0)
    "NoneType",
    0,
    0,
    none_dealloc,       /*tp_dealloc*/ /*never called*/
    0,                  /*tp_vectorcall_offset*/
    0,                  /*tp_getattr*/
    0,                  /*tp_setattr*/
    // ...
    0,                  /*tp_richcompare */
    // ...
    0,                  /*tp_init */
    0,                  /*tp_alloc */
    none_new,           /*tp_new */
};
```

I omitted most of the irrelevant parts. The important thing here is that `_PyNone_Type`'s `tp_richcompare` is `0`, i.e. a null pointer. This is checked for in the [`do_richcompare`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/74d5f61ebd1cb14907bf7dae1ad9c1e676707bc5/Objects/object.c#L643) function:

```c
    if ((f = Py_TYPE(v)->tp_richcompare) != NULL) {
        res = (*f)(v, w, op);
        if (res != Py_NotImplemented)
            return res;
        Py_DECREF(res);
    }
    if (!checked_reverse_op && (f = Py_TYPE(w)->tp_richcompare) != NULL) {
        res = (*f)(w, v, _Py_SwappedOp[op]);
        if (res != Py_NotImplemented)
            return res;
        Py_DECREF(res);
    }
```

Translating for those who don't speak C:

- If the left-hand-side's `tp_richcompare` function is not null, call it, and if its result is not `NotImplemented` then return that result.
- Otherwise if the reverse hasn't already been checked*, and the right-hand-side's `tp_richcompare` function is not null, call it, and if the result is not `NotImplemented` then return that result.

There are some other branches in the code, to fall back to in case none of those branches returns a result. But these two branches are enough to see what's going on. It's not that `type(None).__eq__` returns `NotImplemented`, rather the type doesn't have the corresponding function in the C source code at all. That means the second branch is taken, hence the result you observe.

<sub>*The flag `checked_reverse_op` is set if the reverse direction has already been checked; this happens if the right-hand-side is a strict subtype of the left-hand-side, in which case it takes priority. That doesn't apply in this case since there is no subtype relation between `type(None)` and your class.</sub>

Comment: @KellyBundy Interesting question, but I think the answer to that would be about as long as this answer already is. I am not 100% sure, but I believe `object.__eq__` is defined somewhere else, and that's what you'll get when you look up `type(None).__eq__` since it doesn't override it; but the `==` operator doesn't directly look up `__eq__`, rather it calls the `tp_richcompare` function which is defined by `__eq__` for normal classes but is hardcoded for built-in types.

Comment: This is a perfect low-level explanation, thank you!

Comment: Sorry, I had misread (was hoping I deleted quickly enough). I thought you were showing the `object` C code, i.e., that `object` doesn't have an `__eq__` method (because you were talking about that and because it's in `object.c`).

Comment: @KellyBundy I think it's a relevant question anyway. To be clear, I don't think `object` has a `tp_richcompare` function either, I think the mechanism for looking up `__eq__` is a separate thing, which gets called into from the `==` operator for user-defined types but not for built-in types. But I am not sure where the C source code corresponding to the `object` class is.

Comment: Further down in `do_richcompare`, it implements the default behavior for the comparison operators if `tp_richcompare` doesn't point to an appropriate function: object identity for `==` and `!=`, and `TypeError` for the others.

Comment: @chepner Right, but Kelly Bundy's question was where `None.__eq__` comes from when you write it in Python, since there doesn't seem to be a corresponding implementation of that in C. It's clear that when you call `object.__eq__(1, 2)` you aren't calling `do_richcompare`, because the result is `NotImplemented` instead of `False`.

Comment: To be clearer what I meant: Like I said I thought you were talking about `object`, so I actually wondered where `object.__eq__` comes from. (I had copied your `type(None).__eq__`, which as you showed is `<slot wrapper '__eq__' of 'object' objects>`).

Answer (score 7):

As stated in the docs: `x==y` calls `x.__eq__(y)`, but `None.__eq__(...)` returns `NotImplemented` for anything except the `None` itself (missing piece: why? I don't know), so Python tries the comparison the other way around and calls the `__eq__` from the `MyNone` which always returns `True`.

Update: `None` (the `NoneType` class) does not define its own `__eq__` and uses the default `object.__eq__` which is based on the `is` test: it returns `True` if the argument `is` identical or `NotImplemented` otherwise. (thanks to co-authors)

Comment: `NotImplemented` raised from `__eq__` means the same as if it didn't exist, which allows the interpreter to fall back to the right-side check.

Comment: Can you point me to the place in the docs where the "Python tries the comparison the other way around if `NotImplemented` is returned"-part is described / mentioned? This is important knowledge I was missing. Thanks!

Comment: The missing piece is that `type(None).__eq__` is simply `object.__eq__`, which only ever returns `True` if the two inputs are the same object (by identity, not by value). But actually the part of the source code that implements that behaviour is not reached in this code, since it has lower priority than the right-hand-side's `__eq__` method when it has one. See my answer for details.

Comment: @VPfB `__eq__` always returns `NotImplemented` for non-matching data types, hence an `__eq__` with `None` and anything else would always return `NotImplemented`, isn't it?

Comment: @Rohit Not exactly; whether or not `__eq__` returns `NotImplemented` depends on which implementation of `__eq__` you're using, and some implementations of `__eq__` do return a `True` or `False` result when called on a different type, e.g. `float.__eq__(1.0, 1)` or `float.__eq__(1.0, 2)`. Normally `NotImplemented` means either that the other type is not sufficiently related to be compared by that implementation of `__eq__`, or that the other type is a subtype and its `__eq__` implementation should be used instead.